# How to change local time for testing purposes?

Tags: php, date, time

I'm writing a script, that is based on the current time and it works fine, but I don't want to wait, so I can see, if the script works tomorrow, in 2, 3, 4 days, or a year.

Is there a way to trick the apache server (using php preferred) into thinking that it's a different time? :-)

And if so, is it easy to fix back withnout any perpament consequences?

Comment: If your script is local, did you try to change your system date?

Comment: @Andre matos: Good one! If you wrote that as an answer, I would have picked it as the correct one! Thanks ^^

Comment: +1 for making me realise that I should never assume time() is now.

Comment: Having to change the system clock is a poor solution - you really need to abstract the current time in whatever script you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I presume at some level inside your script you're using the [time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function to get the current time? (If you're not, you most likely should be.)

If so, simply replace the call to time with a call to [mktime](http://www.php.net/mktime), set to the appropriate date/time in the future.

Worse case scenario (if you're not using a PHP script), could just simply change the current system date/time using the system "date" command ("man date" for the details) if you're on Unix/Linux use or the appropriate control panel/system setting, etc. if you're on Windows/Mac OS X, etc. However, I'd really not recommend doing this unless you're using a private test server.

Additionally, as I said in my comment, having to change the system clock is a poor solution - you really need to abstract the current time in whatever script you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with middaparka - changing the local time is all well and good if you're running your script locally, but what about when it's running on a server because it depends on a data/session/something else?

The answer is to just set a variable at the top of your script called $time and set it to time(), then use $time throughout your script instead of time().  Then, when you want to change the time for testing purposes, you only need to change that one line.